# Android Development - Hide related videos from youtube app

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I got the following code to open a channel from Youtube App:

```
        intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/user/User_Name"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

and works fine, but when I see a video, I would like to hide the section "Related videos", is it possible?

I think that, as you can use:

```
        intent.putExtra("query", "Android");
```

To open with a search, maybe, there is something like:

```
        intent.putExtra("related_videos", "False");
```

Is it possible or I am trying something impossible?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You can only specify what video the youtube app should play. If you don't want any other video to show up, you could use the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) and embed the video natively in your app.